# How to name SMD packages in my Pick&Place library

Tags: surface-mount, packages, library

I have massive problem with finding a correct scheme to name the packages correctly in my Pick&Place machine's library.

For example: QFN-16
I have one QFN-16 with 6+6+2+2 leads
and another QFN-16 with 4+4+4+4 leads.
Both also have different outer dimensions.

One is 0.6mm thick and another one maybe 1.0mm
Since height is very important for the Pick&Place machine, I would have to distinguish these again... so I end up with toooo many QFN-16 entries...

However, both are named as "QFN-16" by vendor and manufacturer.

I started naming my parts "QFN-16_3x3_6+6+2+2" and so on, but this gets suuuper confusing and doesn't even include the height.

Any ideas? I'm not using Altium or anything like that. I just do a small production.

Comment: Just append the part number to "QFN16" if you get repeated identical libraries so what - memory is cheap.

Comment: Yes memory is cheap, but if I want to change a parameter, I have to do that in every single package manually. And time is not cheap. :D

Answer (score 6):

There is an naming convention for land patterns in IPC-7351B. It would make sense to use it or something similar for your pick&place library.

The naming convention includes pitch, pin count, body width, length and height, so it might be what you are looking for.

Example:

A QFN package with .5mm pitch, 5mm by 5mm body, 1 mm height and 28 pins would be:
QFN50P500X500X100-28

There is a guide to the naming land patterns [here](https://www.pcb-3d.com/tutorials/ipc-7351b-naming-convention-for-surface-mount-device-3d-models-and-footprints/)

The IPC standard can be bought through the IPC online store.

Comment: Sadly my (poor) software doesn't accept that long names.